# Periodic Sobolev Spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, periodic-functions, elliptic-equations

I would like some reference about Periodic Sobolev Spaces. I found some references, like the book of [R. Teman](https://doi.org/10.1137/1.9781611970050), but all these references deal with Periodic Sobolev Spaces that have the period defined in a cube like $Q=[0,L]^n$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$, i.e. the functions are periodic in all variables. I need Periodic Sobolev Spaces such that the function are periodic only for some variable.

In order to be more precise, I need to define spaces $L^2$ and $H^2$ for functions that satisfy:

$$u(x+Le_1)=u(x+Le_1), \ \ \forall x\in \mathbb{R}^n, \ \ \forall t>0,$$
tha is, they are periodic only for one direction.

Edited: Actually, I need these spaces because I am concerned with the following problem:

$$\begin{cases}
-u_{xx}-au_{yy}+b_1u_{x}+b_2u_{y}+cu=f, & (x,y)\in \mathbb{R}\times (0,1)\\
u(x+L,y)=u(x,y), & (x,y)\in \mathbb{R}\times (0,1)\ \   \text{(periodic condition)}\\
u(x,0)=u_0(x), \ \ u(x,1)=u_1(x) & x\in \mathbb{R},
\end{cases}$$
where  $a,b,c,f \in C^1(\mathbb{R}\times [0,1])$, periodic with respect to $x$ and $u_0,u_1$ are regular enough periodic functions.

Comment: It is $L^2(\mathbb{T} \times \mathbb{R}^{n-1})$ whose basis can be $\frac{1}{\sqrt{L}}e^{2i \pi n x_1 /L} H_l(x_2,\ldots,x_n)$ where $(H_l)$ is a basis of $L^2(\mathbb{R}^{n-1})$.

Comment: Thanks @reuns. Could you give some references? I would like to know the properties os these spaces, because I want to use Lax-Milgram Theorem and I need some embbedings too.

Comment: You should find the simplest example of the problem you really need to solve. For $H^2$ it depends on what you want : $H^2(\mathbb{T})$ is not the same as $H^2([0,1])$.

Comment: The keyword is "product manifold". See for example this paper by Tzvetkov and references: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1011.6185.pdf